# Spring Oauth2 PKCE authorize

Tags: angular, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2, pkce

I am configuring my spring oauth2 to use PKCE authorization. If i test it on browser it works as supposed, But I have some problems impelmenting the Angular part because the default spring security login form is returned after I make a GET to :

```
http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=public&redirect_uri=http://public-client/&scope=read&code_challenge=4cc9b165-1230-4607-873b-3a78afcf60c5
```

I followed this tutorial: https://sultanov.dev/blog/authorization-code-flow-with-pkce-in-spring-security-oauth/

Comment: you need to better describe your problem there is no mention of using angular in that tutorial so getting spring authentication is kind of expected

Comment: @Xesenix my question is how can I replace that automatic login form?

Comment: you would need to replace content served on `/oauth/authorize` but I have no idea where to find it in that example